CMake '3.28.1' is not showing in sdk tools Android Studio Jellyfish
I got this error in my c++ based android project:
[CXX1300] CMake '3.28.1' was not found in SDK, PATH, or by cmake.dir property.

when I tried to install through SDK Tools section of SDK manager I can't find the required version of cmake there..
How can I solve it ?
I tried to download manually but it contains different set of files and folder (more files/folders) than I can see there in existing other versions installed location.

CMake 3.28.1 isn't included in Android SDK.
Simply download and install CMake 3.28.1 from here: CMake 3.28, make sure you select the right file for your OS.
You don't need to install it in the Android SDK folder as it should be automatically added to your PATH variable (that's how it works on macOS). If it isn't, just make sure to add the installation folder to your system PATH variable.
